# Solaris 10 stuck at boot

Tags: solaris-10, sparc

I have an old sparc T5220 server which had been running solaris 10 for sometime now.
I ran some patches on the server and when i rebooted, it got stucked at

```
SunOS Release 5.10 Version Generic_153153-04 64-bit
Copyright (c) 1983, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Ethernet address = 0:21:28:13:4a:d6
```

When i tried booting using `boot -sv` , it stucked at

```
st2 at fp5: unit-address w5001438016052ea5,0: 20a00
st2 is /pci@0/pci@0/pci@8/pci@0/pci@a/SUNW,qlc@0/fp@0,0/st@w5001438016052ea5,0
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@8/pci@0/pci@a/SUNW,qlc@0/fp@0,0/st@w5001438016052ea5,0 (st2):
    <HP      Ultrium 5-SCSI  >
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@8/pci@0/pci@a/SUNW,qlc@0/fp@0,0/st@w5001438016052ea5,0 (st2) online
```

So, i decided to do a reinstall of the OS using solaris 11.3 iso via the ilom redirection but i cant find rcdrom.

Any help in fixing the boot failure or reinstall of the os would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've been able to fix this by upgrading the firmware of the server from the ilom cli.

All is fine now